# How Can I Setup Apache and PHP 8.1 and Run PHP with macOS 12

Tags: php, macos, apache

I Try To Setup PHP 8.1 on MacOS 12 Using brew but not working
I can't found LoadModule php_module in Config File

Answer (score 0):

I just finished setting it up.  Using homebrew "brew install php" and configuring my httpd.conf

#PHP was deprecated in macOS 11 and removed from macOS 12
Create new Line
LoadModule php_module /path/php/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so

'<FilesMatch .php$> SetHandler application/x-httpd-php

in '<'IfModule dir_module> add index.php

You will need to create a Signing Certificate

```
https://www.simplified.guide/macos/apache-php-homebrew-codesign
```

Sign the files libphp.so and the file "opcache.so"

Because of different Chips Intel or Mac the paths will vary.

Afterwards it should work.

Answer (score -1):

You can use MAMP or XAMPP. Following is download link :

MAMP : [MAMP Downalod](https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/)

XAMPP : [XAMPP Download](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)

These are the easiest way to setup LAMP in Mac OS 12 (Monetery).